Is a countdown timer possible within a push notification?
I want to create a push notification that includes a countdown timer.
Is it possible to create it without using SwiftUI? If so, how can I do it?
I am looking for something similar to the timer shown in the red square:


A countdown timer within a push notification isn't possible because push notifications show a static content once fired which can't be changed
However, I believe you can use a workaround e.g
Use in app notifications
When you receive a push notification, you can trigger an in-app notification whose content you can adjust. You can get some more details here, What are in app notifications Link

Your second approach will quickly run into throttling restrictions and Apple will stop delivering them.
